# Elasticsearch for laravel - Get documents matching one or more categories?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

The following code works for me and returns the blog posts matching the query

```
 $params = [
            'index' => 'blog',
            'type' => 'post',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'multi_match' => [
                        'query' => $request->get('query'),
                        'fields' => ['title', 'description']
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
$response = \Elasticsearch::search($params); // works perfect
```

How can I change the code above so I can get all documents which their category matches one of the **$categories** values

The $categories variable is a variable that I'm getting from check boxes,

I tried with the code below but for some reason it return empty result :

```
 // $categories = $request->get('categories');
 $categories = ["News", "Technology"];
 $params = [
            'index' => 'blog',
            'type' => 'post',
            'body' =>  [

                "query"=> [
                    "filtered"=> [
                        "query"=> [
                            "match_all"=> []
                        ],
                        "query"=>[
                            "terms"=> [
                                "category"=> $categories
                            ]
                        ]

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

 $response = \Elasticsearch::search($params); // return 0 hits
```

Any idea on how I can get the documents based on one or more categories instead of getting them based on a matching words ?

Answer (score 0):

You are having two `query` clauses at the same level inside `filtered` clause which is not allowed.

```
"query"=> [
                    "filtered"=> [
                        "query"=> [  <-- (1)
                            "match_all"=> []
                        ],
                        "query"=>[ <-- (2)
                            "terms"=> [
                                "category"=> $categories
                            ]
                        ]

                    ]
```

If you are trying to query only the categories, you should remove the first clause. You can write your query as

```
                  "query"=> [
                    "filtered"=> [
                        "query"=>[
                            "terms"=> [
                                "category"=> $categories
                            ]
                        ]
                     ]  
                    ]
```